# Drupal: After copying database from staging, all my urls are wrong

Tags: php, drupal, drupal-7

I copied my drupal database from staging server to my local server for development. I cleared cache, and truncated all cache tables.

All my links still have the base url from the staging server. There is no base path defined in settings.php

I scanned the entire project files, but the url is not present in any file. So the conclusion is that it has to be hidden somewhere in the database.

Does anyone know where I should start looking?

Answer (score 0):

Sorry, I posted the question after looking for half an hour, but I accidently found out instants after posting it.

For anyone else with this problem. I hade domains module installed which does some heavy rewrting of the domain paths. There was my problem.